# Show that the Jordan measure is zero

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if C is a Jordan measurable and a measure 0 set then $\int_C 1 =0$ (this is, its Jordan Measure is zero)

My approach is to show that $L(X_C,P)=0$ for all partition $P$, But I am not sure in how to proceed in this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Note:

My definition of measure 0 is that there exist rectangles $R_1,R_2,\ldots$ such that: $C \subset \bigcup R_i$ and the the sum of the volumes $\sum v(R_i) < \epsilon$.

Jordan measurable for me is a set tha is bounded and its boundary has measure zero.

Comment: Is the collection of rectangles finite?

Comment: No, it is infinite :)

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be finite for Jordan measure? And infinite for Lebesgue measure? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

If there is some non trivial rectangle $R$ such that
$\inf_{x \in R} 1_C(x) \neq 0$ then you must have $R \subset C$, in which
case $C$ cannot have measure zero. Hence $\inf_{x \in R} 1_C(x) = 0$ for
all rectangles $R$, and so
$L(1_C, P) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and this proves that the integral is zero right?

Comment: But why is this: then you must have R⊂C, in which case C cannot have measure zero.

Comment: This shows that if the integral exists it is zero.

Comment: Ok, and what about my above comment?

Comment: Well, one way is to note that if $R \subset C$ then $C$ cannot have measure zero. Otherwise if $R \subset C \subset \cup_i R_i$ and so $\sum_i v(R_i) \ge v(R)>0$. Then $v(C) \ge v(R)$.

Comment: But the integral exist right?, beacuse C is Jordan measurable

Comment: A bounded function with support contained in a bounded set is Riemann integrable **iff** the set of discontinuities has measure zero. The set of discontinuities of $1_C$ are $C$, hence $1_C$ is integrable.

Comment: Yes, well we have seen that a function is Riemann integrable iff the set of discontinuities is of measure zero, is beacuse I ddnt understand the part of the support, and in the other hand This completes the above proof right?

Comment: It just means that the set of points at which $f \neq 0$ is contained in a bounded set. You should show that the set of discontinuities of $1_C$ are $C$ and then you can use the integrability result.

Comment: But like I have said, we know that $1_C =X_C$ is integrable iff $C$ is the boundary of C is of measure zero, then with this and your answer we are done rght?

Comment: Yes. Since $1_C$ is integrable, and $L(1_C,P) = 0$ for all partitions $R$, you must have $\int 1_C = 0$.

Comment: Then resuming and writing everything we have that Since $C$ is Jordan measurable $fr(C)$ has measure zero, then $1_C=X_C$ is riemman integrable, and then we have the following: If there is some non trivial rectangle $R$ such that
$\inf_{x \in R} 1_C(x) \neq 0$ then you must have $R \subset C$, in which
case $C$ cannot have measure zero. Hence $\inf_{x \in R} 1_C(x) = 0$ for
all rectangles $R$, and so
$L(1_C, P) = 0$. And therefore $\int_C 1 =0$ Correct?

Comment: Correct, because if $f$ is integrable, we have $\int f = \sup_P L(f,P)$.

Comment: Ok :), but well in this case $f=1=X_C$ :)